# Cypher query DISTINCT

Tags: neo4j, aggregate, cypher

I have simple use case but still can't find the solution....

I have **Questions** nodes each question has **category** , each category can have many questions.
I want to do the following:

retrieve 5 questions where each one of them is from different category.

tried the following but it is not what I am looking for cause I still get questions from the same category.

```
 START question=node:__types__(className = "com.socialist.server.graph.entities.Question")
 RETURN distinct(question.category), question
 LIMIT 5
```

What is the correct query for that use-case? 
Your answer is highly appriciated.

Comment: how did you model the fact that each question has a category? From your query it looks like that category is a property of a question. Wouldn't it make more sense to introduce nodes for categories?

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment... lets say I have Category nodes : question-[:RELATE]->category how it will help to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work, but if you have a lot per category it won't be the best efficiency:

```
START question=node:__types__(className = "com.socialist.server.graph.entities.Question")
RETURN question.category, head(collect(question))
LIMIT 5
```

Also, soon (hopefully by 2.0 release) there will be a good way to get a random item out of a collection, something like this:

```
START question=node:__types__(className = "com.socialist.server.graph.entities.Question")
WITH question.category as category, collect(question) as questions
RETURN category, questions[rand() * length(questions)]
LIMIT 5
```